# How to upgrade WinForm infragistics v12.1 to 14.1

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have add new infragistics references version 14.1 to my references(v12.1) by using utility and so when i add references with new version than i got some errors...

> "Error 6404    The type or namespace name 'Infragistics' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?  ...etc"

it is still finding references of the old version

Comment: Have you talked to Infragistics? http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/

Comment: >Error 9 The type 'Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Infragistics2.Win.Misc.v12.1, Version=12.1.20121.1001, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb'.

Comment: When you install Infragistics WinForms you should have an utility called `Version Utility`. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Infragistics 2014, you should see a menu item in Visual Studio called INFRAGISTICS.  Click on that and click on Check for Updates.  It will scan your projects for old references, and upgrade all the namespaces and controls to the latest versions.  Click on the Upgrade button next to each project that comes up in the list.  This will remove all the errors.

Comment: This basically worked for me but it wasn't the top menu Infragistics->Check for Updates but rather the "Update Infragistics Version..." in the context menu for the solution. Also on 2014 version.

Answer (score -1):

Check references to Infragistics dll(s) in your application's config file.